# How resize a cxgrid with the mouse?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, size, tcxgrid

I have 4 cxgrid into a cxTabSheet, 3 aligned albottom and 1 aligned alClient...
When the mouse is over the edge of any cxgrid, the cursor mouse doesn´t change to the crSize(NS, WE, NESW, NWSE) and cannot select the border of grid for drag the mouse and resize it.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do this, without writing any code, is to use one or more splitters on your form: see TSplitter and the Devex custom version, TcxSplitter, in the online help.

To use, place one or more splitters on the form orientated to allow resizing of the grid(s) as you wish, then place the grids on the appropriate areas of the splitters, or on panels on the splitters.  One splitter can be placed inside another, so that you can have one resizable area inside another.

Comment: I unknown totally that component. Never used spliitters, I did not know existed... Go to Investigate more. Thanks

Comment: @NizamUlMulk:  Did this answer your question?